# UIWindow in Xcode 6 templates

Tags: ios, swift

I have a simple question, why is the main (and only UIWindow) on all of the Apple templates in Xcode declared as a var, rather than a let.

```
var window: UIWindow?
```

As I understand it we should use let wherever possible, and especially where the instance won't change.

Also using let with objects still allows you to modify their properties (frame etc).

I'm having a little trouble understanding when to use let with object (class types).

I assumed something like `CLLocationManager` and `UIWindow` would be perfect examples of when to use let with objects, but Apple don't seem to use let in their code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Properties defined with the `let` keyword *must have a value by the time the object is initialized*. The window isn't created during initialisation, so it can't be a let.

It's the same situation for view controllers - none of the outlets, or indeed the view properties, can be lets, because they don't exist at initialisation, but are created later when the view is required.

`let` properties don't really work well for UIKit and view controllers - by design, view controllers don't do a lot of work on initialisation, and you can only set up lets at that point. You are absolutely correct in that let properties would be great for things like a location manager or a managed object context, but as it turns out `lazy var` is often a better bet.

In my (limited, like everyone!) Swift experience, `let` properties are great for making immutable model classes, and local `let`s are the default for creating references in-code.

You can use let properties and define them right there, so for a location manager:

```
let locationManager = CLLocationManager()
```

Think more about what information you need to create whatever's going into the property. If it can be made from scratch without any context, do it like the example above. If it needs to have a delegate or any other properties passed in, you'll probably be creating or setting it after initialisation so a let isn't appropriate.

Comment: Thanks for the information, can't the window property be set to nil though? and then be set later? --- if not what's the point of optional lets?

Comment: What do you mean by an optional let? You mean as in `let window : UIWindow?` ? If that isn't set to anything during initialisation, it can't be changed later. That's literally the point of let properties.

Comment: Thanks for baring with me on this... so I understand what you're saying, but I thought the point of optionals is that they could be set to nil during init and later set to some object? ---- If not used like this why use "let optionals". they might as well not be optional as they will always be set to something by init?]

Comment: They might be left as nil. You wouldn't be able to do that without it being an optional.

Comment: Ahh I get it now. Just for my understanding can you suggest a few class types that might be best used as let? - I understand that you only use let if you don't want to change the reference, so therefore you shouldn't use it when it's likely you'll need to change the object. However would something like CLLocationManager, be a good example of when to use let? - can you maybe give me some other examples

Comment: OK, I've updated the answer. Does that make sense? We're all really feeling our way with Swift at the moment...

Comment: Perfect - thank you very much and enjoy the weekend!

Answer (score 2):

If you define window property as `let`, then UIKit framework will not be able to set `window` property of your app delegate when instantiating your default view controller from main storyboard.

So the answer is:

If you want to do everything in code manually, you can make window property to be defined with let. This way you must initialize it in `init(...)` method of your `AppDelegate`.

Otherwise, if you want to use storyboards and have them instantiated automatically with default view controller then you must define `window` as `var` and enjoy routines that apple perform for you.

Comment: Again I don't understand why the UIWindow can't be nil (as it's an optional) until the storyboard assigns it?

Answer (score 2):

It is ought to be initialized inside the `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` function. That way you can create different windows that suit your needs. For example:

- The application may be being launched in the background to perform a task - no need to initialize a window here.
- Application may be being launched by a notification - a different window object may be created.

Also, as pointed out by @Keenle, if you're using interface builder to shape your application, the window is created and assigned at runtime. In no way this could be done if the `window` property was constant.